# Grafana templating merge variables

Tags: grafana, prometheus

I'm looking for a solution to merge two templating variables in grafana(data source: prometheus).

My use case is:

I've my first variable:

```
deployment = label_values(kube_deployment_labels{namespace="$namespace"},deployment)
```

and the second one:

```
statefulset = label_values(kube_statefulset_labels{namespace="$namespace"},statefulset)
```

What I'm looking for is a only one dropdown menu(selector) because in my dashboard I wan't to be able to select a deployment or a statefulset but not both at the same time.

I've tried at the different side:

1) With prometheus by using a query like this:

```
 kube_deployment_labels{namespace="$namespace"} or kube_statefulset_labels{namespace="$namespace"}
```

But in this case I'm not able to extract the labels(could be "deployment" or statefulset")

2) It seems not possible to perform a merge of two template variables in grafana like this:

```
$deployment,$statefulset
```

Maybe I've missed something...

Thanks,

Matt

Comment: I had exactly the same issue and solved it by using `label_values(kube_pod_labels{namespace="$namespace"}, label_app)`. This query returns names of all deployments, stateful sets and daemon sets. As far as I know, it's not possible to merge two variables.

Answer (score 1):

I do it by creating two separate variable and give them same `label` name.
Since the label name is same it will only show one drop-down.

https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/variables/templates-and-variables/#basic-variable-options

Comment: I've tried this in Grafana 8.2.0 and couldn't get it to work. Grafana creates two separate dropdowns with the same name.